# How to show after small change the intersection between two convex shapes still belongs to an open set

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Assume two convex shapes $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (both $A$ and $B$ are compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$), and denote their intersection as $C = A \cap B$. Let $C$ belong to an open set $D$, i.e., $C \subset D$. How can we show that after small changes in the position and orientation to $A$ and $B$, which is denoted as $\bar{A}$ and $bar{B}$, respectively, their new intersection $\bar{C} = \bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$ still belongs to $D$, i.e., $\bar{C} \subset D$?

Comment: Well, obviously you can't, since it is trivial to come up with counter-examples. For example, if $A$ and $B$ are open, then so is $C$, and $D$ could be $C$ itself. Any change in $A$ or $B$ that doesn't just shrink their intersection would therefore serve as a counter-example. What made you suspect this might be true.

Comment: Sorry, we also need to assume $A$ and $B$ are compact sets. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Then it has nothing to do with convexity. Compactness alone is sufficient. There is a minimum distance $>0$ between $C$ and the complement of $D$. As long as the changes are small enough to leave $\bar C$ in that distance, it will still be within $D$.